# Does fluentd depend on rsyslog?

Tags: rsyslog, fluentd

Still wrapping my head around logging technology. I'm following the [fluentd to graylog2 recipe](http://www.fluentd.org/guides/recipes/graylog2) but I don't understand this step:

```
Open /etc/rsyslog.conf and add the following line to the beginning of the file: *.* @127.0.0.1:5140 Then, restart rsyslogd by running sudo /etc/init.d/rsyslog restart.
```

What's supposed to listen on 127.0.0.1:5140? Is rsyslog a fluentd dependency?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Parse Syslog Messages Robustly](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/parse-syslog):

> The problem with syslog is that services have a wide range of log
>   format, and no single parser can parse all syslog messages
>   effectively.

Rsyslog seems the recommended way to forward logs to fluentd.

Answer (score 0):

Fluentd listens on the port 5140 if you enable the Rsyslog input. Changing the line in

> /etc/rsyslogd.conf

forwards the traffic from Rsyslog to Fluentd.

However, if you don't want to turn on Rsyslog you can just send the traffic straight to port 5140.